# On text change create automatically dropdownlist

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to create Dropdownlist when text change in `TextBox` in c#.

without using dropdownlist.

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Tag="Original Data"></asp:TextBox>
```

I want to modify this tag and generate automatic dropdownlist

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create UserControl to modify this tag here is example for modifying ASP.NET tag
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/322923/Dropdown-TextBox